# How to divide a string into substrings in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++

I am programming in VC++ (.NET) trying to divide the string

> "2A4B12C34C54D"

into different variables so at the end the values of my variables are:

```
Var1=2;
Var2=4;
Var3=12;
Var4=34;
Var5=54;
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Is this your home work? Basically make a loop read one character by character store in a temp string variable when meet the reading character is not 0-9 pop up the string variable convert it to integer variable become Var1.. Step by step you can get Var2 ..... util the end of string

Comment: I know, but how do I read just one char at the time? I am new to VC++, and I don't know the method.

Comment: the lazy fix, google it !

Comment: First question: are you talking about Visual C++, .Net, or Managed C++/CLI? Those are all different things!

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this in my head and did not test, but what you want is approximate to the following code:

```
void MyClass::Split(const CString& input)
{
     int pos_number_began= INT_MAX;

     CArray<CString> output;
     for (int i=0; i<input.GetLength(); i++)
     {
         if(isdigit(input[i]))
             if(pos_number_began == INT_MAX)
                 pos_number_began= i;
         else
         {
             if(pos_number_began != INT_MAX)
                 output.Add(input.Mid(pos_number_began, i-1));

              pos_number_began= INT_MAX;
          }
      }


       if(pos_number_began != INT_MAX)
           output.Add(input.Mid(pos_number_began, input.GetLength()-1));

        // Now do what you want with the output array


}
```